# LINQ string contains another string case insensitive

Tags: c#, linq, windows-8, linq-to-objects

I'm working in a C# Windows 8 Metro app and I'm trying to filter an `ObservableCollection<T>` using LINQ where a property contains some string, and I need that it will be case insensitive.

```
 var searchResults = from _rest in App.ViewModel.Restaurants
                     where  _rest.Name.IndexOf(queryText,
                                 StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0
                     select _rest;
```

I work around

- `Using string1.Contains(string2).ToUpper()` in both strings.
- `Using string1.Contains(string2).ToLower()` in both strings.
- `Using string1.IndexOf(string2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0`.
- `Using string1.IndexOf(string2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0`.
- `Using String.Compare(string1, string2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)`.

But no one of this methods works for me in a case insensitive way, works ok if I write the name correctly.

Has someone have the same issue in Windows 8??

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: Can you give a short but complete example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: They aren't Continental European restaurant names are they? ;-)

Comment: Does it work as you want it to if you apply the same LINQ expression in for example a .NET 4(.0) WPF application?

Comment: Made a simple .NET 4.5 Metro application (VS 2011 Beta, En-US culture) and applied your LINQ expression. Works as expected. Which culture are you using?

Comment: Can you give us some examples?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I'm working in ES-es Culture.

Comment: What kind of example did you mean?? I'm loading the ObservableCollection<Restaurant> deserializating an UTF-8 XML document, I have no issues here and the collection is populated fine.

For example I have around 30 restaurants that contains "Despensa" in their names, if I search the word "Despensa", my app shows this 30 results, but if I search "despensa", "DESPENSA", or "DesPensA" the app shows me no results.

I'll try to make a new empty Metro app this morning.

Answer (score 1):

Write you own Extension Method

```
public static class MetroHelper
{
    public static bool ContainsInvariant(this string mainText, string queryText)
    {
        return mainText.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(queryText.ToUpperInvariant());
    }
}
```

and use in your application

```
var searchResults = from _rest in App.ViewModel.Restaurants
                 where  _rest.Name.ContainsInvariant(queryText)
                 select _rest;
```

That's what I did.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var searchResults = from _rest in App.ViewModel.Restaurants
                         where  _rest.Name.IndexOf(queryText,
                                     StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0
                         select _rest;
```

Comment: StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase is not available in Metro Apps.